# How to start a new Intent by using an Adapter?

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

CategoriesListScreen.java

```
public class CategoriesListScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{

private static final String TAG = "CategoriesListScreen";

//vars
private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getImages();
}

private void getImages(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps.");

    mImageUrls.add("https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4636/25316407448_de5fbf183d_o.jpg");
    mNames.add("Havasu Falls");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/tpsnoz5bzo501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Trondheim");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/qn7f9oqu7o501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Portugal");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Rocky Mountain National Park");


    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/0h2gm1ix6p501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Mahahual");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/k98uzl68eh501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Frozen Lake");


    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/glin0nwndo501.jpg");
    mNames.add("White Sands Desert");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/obx4zydshg601.jpg");
    mNames.add("Austrailia");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.imgur.com/ZcLLrkY.jpg");
    mNames.add("Washington");

    initRecyclerView();

}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview");

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have Adapter for RecyclerView:

MyAdapter.java

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mImageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> mImageUrl) {
    this.mNames = names;
    this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
   //as the user clicks on different images activity correspond to that image should start.

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrl.get(position))
            .into(holder.); //i am confused what to write here..

    holder.onBind(position);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mImageUrl.size();
}

 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            CircleImageView image;
            TextView textView;

            image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(getAdapterPosition()){
                case 0:
                    // start activity 0
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // start activity 1
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(mContext, CarsActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to setup horizontal recyclerview and I need to start a new Intent activity corresponding to an image. For example, If the user clicks on first image then he should be redirected to first.class, if the user clicks on second image then he should be redirected to second.class and so on..
I am very confused. I am not able to figure out what to write inside onBindViewHolder. Any help would be appreciated! :)

layout_listitem.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Canada"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want different classes for each element in the list?

Comment: Yes. If the user clicks on image 1 from the list then he should be redirected to first.class activity. and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
   holder.onBind(mImageUrl.get(position), mNames.get(position));
}



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        CircleImageView imageView; // <-- move image here
        TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);


            imageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);// <-- only this line is added to constructor
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//here ViewHolder implements OnClickListener

            final Context ctx = v.getContext();
            Intent intent;

            switch(getAdapterPosition){                
                case 0:                  
                   intent = new Intent(ctx, FirstActivity.class);
                   ctx.startActivity(intent);
                break;
                case 1:                  
                  intent = new Intent(ctx, SecondActivity.class);
                  ctx.startActivity(intent);
                break
            }
        }
        void onBind(String url, String name){ // call this method from onBindViewHolder

            textView.setText(name);

            Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                 .asBitmap()
                 .load(url)
                 .into(imageView); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated MyViewHolder Class as per your code.please check the updated code. However I am still confused what to write inside onBindViewHolder. My onBindViewHolder is still empty.

Comment: @Sahil i have update my answer see if your question is solved

Comment: I updated onBindViewHolder and I also have added the Activity class where the RecyclerView shall be displayed. I entered the image url to display in the circular image view. Please check the updated code. I believe you can help me with this. I am new to RecyclerView..

Comment: @Sahil move `Glide` to `onBind` of `ViewHolder` from `onBindViewHolder` as my answer

Answer (score 0):

onBindViewHolder has the element position as second parameter, for this solution you obviously need to always know that the position of each different object for each position in the list is always the same

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    ..
    switch(position) 
    {
        case 0:
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FirstClass.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        break;
        case 1:
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondClass.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to run this code.